How to prevent React from re-rendering the whole IFrame?
I m working on a simple react UI which uses React beautiful Drag and Drag Library for Dragging and Dropping
The Items  however use an iframe with a third party application widget in.
When I drag these they re-render the entire iframe which I don't want to happen, is there a way to stop this?
See example of this happening.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-beautiful-dnd-sample-forked-49cc7x?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx
How can we prevent from reloading ?

i don't think it is possible: react-beatiful-dnd remount draggables after reorder, which cause iframe reload

Is there other Drag and Drop library , which avoids this behaviour ?

You can memoized your component something like const MemoizedCard = React.memo(Card); and use this  <MemoizedCard id={card.id} title={card.title} />

Yes , I tried it , but it isnt working .

WIll Portal help in any manner , any Idea ?

I don't know if it is possible to avoid this behavior, but you can try other libraries, for example DND formkit

Can you provide your code please? it will be of big help, perhaps you're using something that's causing the re-render, or perhaps we can based on your code fix this issue. instead of just guessing for a fix...

@OmAiRKH , the code is in Codesandbox , its in my question itself

And your sandbox is not found. Please check before sharing.

I think I can give you some suggestions that could help:

Try useMemo or by moving the iframe outside the component that is frequently experiencing a state change.



import React, { memo } from 'react';

const IframeComponent = memo(({ src }) => {
  console.log('Iframe rendering(This will not log after initial render unless src changes) ');
  return (
    <iframe src={src} width="100%" height="400px" />
  );
});

export default IframeComponent;



You can now use theIframeComponent like <IframeComponent src="https://example.com" />

Using React's key prop: You can use a fixed key prop on the iframe.

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks for the answer , the Iframe is of PowerBI report , which I dont have any control on it

His solution remains correct. Wrapping the <Card> component from your sandox in memo would solve your issue.
If the Iframe comes from some controller  you have no control over then you need to wrap the component that calls that component in memo - carefully ensuring your props are memoized.

The child component isn't rendering, I have put up a console log, but the issue is that, the iframe reloads during drag and drop

you could use react life cycle method shouldComponentUpdate
here is example how it can be used :
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
  
class Counter1 extends Component { 
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) { 
    // Rendering the component only if  
    // passed props value is changed 
  
    if (nextProps.value !== this.props.value) { 
      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 
  render() { 
    console.log("Counter 1 is calling"); 
    return ( 
      <div> 
        <h2>Counter 1:</h2> 
        <h3>{this.props.value}</h3> 
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Add</button> 
      </div> 
    ); 
  } 
} 
  
export default Counter1; 

you can use this to prevent your component update unnessary or you can check why its updating.

You can use flex and order in this case
import { useState } from "react";
import { DragDropContext, Draggable, Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

const getCards = (count) =>
  Array.from({ length: count }, (v, k) => k).map((i) => ({
    id: i + 1,
    title: `title${i}`,
    sortOrder: i + 1,
  }));

export default function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(getCards(5));

  let onDragEnd = ({ source, destination }) => {
    if (!destination) return;
    let isDraggingDown = source.index < destination.index;
    // re-ordering cards based on source and destination
    setCards((state) =>
      state.map((card) => {
        if (isDraggingDown) {
          if (
            card.sortOrder <= destination.index &&
            card.sortOrder >= source.index
          ) {
            if (card.sortOrder == source.index) {
              card.sortOrder = destination.index;
            } else {
              card.sortOrder = card.sortOrder - 1;
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (
            card.sortOrder >= destination.index &&
            card.sortOrder <= source.index
          ) {
            if (card.sortOrder == source.index) {
              card.sortOrder = destination.index;
            } else {
              card.sortOrder = card.sortOrder + 1;
            }
          }
        }
        return card;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId="list-1" type="CARD">
          {({ innerRef, droppableProps, placeholder }) => (
            <div ref={innerRef} {...droppableProps}>
              <ul
                style={{
                  listStyle: "none",
                  padding: "0",
                  display: "flex",
                  flexDirection: "column",
                }}
              >
                {cards.map((card, index) => (
                  <Draggable
                    key={card.id}
                    draggableId={`${card.id}`}
                    index={card.sortOrder}
                  >
                    {({ innerRef, draggableProps, dragHandleProps }) => {
                      const { style, ..._draggableProps } = draggableProps;
                      return (
                        <li
                          ref={innerRef}
                          {..._draggableProps}
                          {...dragHandleProps}
                          style={{ ...style, order: card.sortOrder }}
                        >
                          <Card id={card.id} title={card.title} />
                        </li>
                      );
                    }}
                  </Draggable>
                ))}
              </ul>
              {placeholder}
            </div>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
    </div>
  );
}

const Card = ({ id, title }) => {
  return (
    <div className="box">
      <div>{`handle: ${id}`}</div>

      <iframe
        width="100%"
        height="166"
        allow="autoplay"
        src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/379775672&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=true&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

Changes:

ul element need to been a display property to 'flex' in order to use 'order' property in its items
Need to add some external style to li
Also need some logic change inside onDragEnd for re ordering items


I got it to stop re-rendering by putting the src attribute in a useMemo.
I actually put everything that might force a re-rendering in some sort of memo and I think that useMemo for the src was what got it to stop reloading.

Just use it in useEffect to prevent side effects.
Before:
const onDragEnd: OnDragEndResponder = ({ source, destination }) => {
if (!destination) return;
const copiedCards = [...cards];
const [draggedCard] = copiedCards.splice(source.index, 1);
copiedCards.splice(destination.index, 0, draggedCard);
setCards(copiedCards.map((card, index) => ({ ...card, sortOrder: index })));};

After:
  let onDragEnd;
  useEffect(() => {
  onDragEnd = ({ source, destination }) => {
  if (!destination) return;
  const copiedCards = [...cards];
  const [draggedCard] = copiedCards.splice(source.index, 1);
  copiedCards.splice(destination.index, 0, draggedCard);
  setCards(
    copiedCards.map((card, index) => ({ ...card, sortOrder: index })));
};});


Your useEffect is not preventing side effects; furthermore, in this particular case we want a side-effect. It's an event-handler after all.
